# Get Pods of Unique Namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm running the following command from Terminal to retrieve the status of a specific pod amongst all of my namespaces. The problem I'm trying to solve is to only return the **unique** namespaces that have a status of 'Evicted'

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -lapp=myapp | grep Evicted | sort | uniq -c
```

**This is an example of the results I get:**

```
NAMESPACE       READY       STATUS
customer-1       0/1        Evicted
customer-3       0/1        Evicted
customer-2       0/1        Evicted
customer-3       0/1        Evicted
customer-1       0/1        Evicted
```

**This is the result I'm after:**

```
NAMESPACE       READY       STATUS
customer-1       0/1        Evicted
customer-2       0/1        Evicted
customer-3       0/1        Evicted
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -lapp=myapp | grep Evicted | awk {'print $1'} | uniq -c
```

should do the trick for you. Uniq wasn't having an effect because of non-unique pod names.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you a different approach using kubectl command arguments:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector=status.phase=Evicted --sort-by=.metadata.namespace -o custom-columns=NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace | uniq
```

Here we are using some arguments to filter, sort and define custom columns output.

The output will be similar to this:

```
NAMESPACE
customer-1
customer-2
customer-3
```

Comment: This match your needs? Let me know if you need any further help.